# How to add translation class/model to an existing Sylius model?

Tags: sylius

I am trying to add translations to Sylius' product variant model, but having some trouble configuring the resource.

When dealing with custom models it is easy to add translation classes, just create the necessary classes with the right interfaces and then include them in the resources configuration file, like below:

```
# resources.yml
app.orientation:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\Orientation\Orientation
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\Orientation\OrientationTranslation
```

I have already added the necessary classes to the product variant and customised the product variant itself to make it translatable. The last step is to activate the translation classes (only the model in this case). The problem is that when I try to add the model to my config.yml I get the following error:

> Unrecognized option "translation" under
>   "sylius_product.resources.product_variant"

So how am I supposed to enable the translation of the product variant model?

Configuration reference:

```
# config.yml
sylius_product:
    resources:
        product_variant:
            classes:
                factory: AppBundle\Factory\Product\ProductVariantFactory
                model: AppBundle\Entity\Product\ProductVariant
                form:
                    default: AppBundle\Form\Type\Product\ProductVariantType
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\Product\ProductVariantTranslation
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "tranlation" entry in the `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ProductBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php` file. 
That why you get that error.

I guess you just have to define your translation class in the sylius_resource section

```
    sylius_resource:
        app.product:
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductTranslation
```

Comment: That won't work unfortunately because you have to configure the classes node. Exception message:

`The child node "classes" at path "sylius_resource.resources.app.product_variant" must be configured.`

Comment: What about adding it also and pointing to the Sylius default one ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ylastapis comments I came up with the following solution:

```
sylius.product_variant:
            classes:
                factory: AppBundle\Factory\Product\ProductVariantFactory
                interface: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ProductVariantInterface
                model: AppBundle\Entity\Product\ProductVariant
                repository: AppBundle\Repository\ProductVariantRepository
                form: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductVariantType
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\Product\ProductVariantTranslation
```

Which I entered in my resources.yml file along with other custom resources. A clear drawback with this solution is that it's quite tightly coupled to the ProductVariant. As I have to reference all types of classes which are not using the default classes provided by the resource bundle.